# Failover redundancy without code duplication?

Tags: c#

I'm submitting data to a web service which I occasionally lose connection to (internet in my country isn't so great).

The web service has the main endpoint and a failover endpoint.

I'm handling a connection error essentially by duplicating the code that interacts with the web service. Values that I'm working with don't really matter so to keep this example as simple as I can, I've removed a lot of complexity.

```
private bool _testing = true;

protected async void GetPatient_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (_testing)
    {
        await SendTestRequestToWebService(foo, bar);
    }
}

private async Task SendTestRequestToWebService(string foo, string bar)
{
    try
    {
        using (var client = Service.ServiceGatewayClient())
        {
            // Do stuff on the service.
            var response = client.Operation(foo, bar);
            ParseServiceResponse(response);
        }
    }
    catch (System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException ex)
    {
        // Couldn't connect to the service, failover to the backup.
        using (var client = ServiceFailover.ServiceGatewayClient())
        {
            // Do stuff on the service.                
            var response = client.Operation(foo, bar);
            ParseFailoverServiceResponse(response);
        }
    }
}

private void ParseServiceResponse(Service.OperationResponse response)
{
    // Do stuff with the response from the service operation.
}

private void ParseFailoverServiceResponse(ServiceFailover.OperationResponse response)
{
    // Do stuff with the response from the failover service operation.
    // This code is identical to what's in ParseServiceResponse,
    // only difference is the parameter type.
}
```

So the try and catch blocks are basically identical and so are the parse functions but the object types used in all of this are different.

Is there a more intuitive way of doing this that can take into account the different types without duplicating the code?

## EDIT

Here's an example of common logic that would be in the parsing functions:

```
    private void ParseFailoverResponse(ServiceFailover.OperationResponse response)
{
    // The payload is just a string containing delimited data returned by the service.
    var payload = response.ResponsePayload;

    if (payload.Contains("NODATA"))
    {
        ResultMessage.Text = "No data was returned by the service request.";
    }
    else
    {
        var _response = ParseResponseRecord(response.responsePayload);
        if (_response.ResultCode == MSVResultCode.Invalid)
        {
            ResultMessage.Text = _response.Result;
            ResultMessage.CssClass = "text-danger";
        }
        else if (_response.ResultCode == MSVResultCode.Valid)
        {
            var _payload = payload.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
            // List patients and main member as returned by the medical aid.
            // If none are returned, prompt the user to add the patient manually.
            var patients = ParsePatientRecords(_payload);
            PatientsRepeater.DataSource = patients;
            PatientsRepeater.DataBind();

            ResultPanel.Visible = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems a good deal for generics. However without any idea of your `ServiceGatewayClient`- and your `OperationResponse `-classes and your common logic it´s hard to suggest any further.

Comment: Would you consider using some external library to handle this?

Comment: Is there any connection between classes? For instance `Service.ServiceGatewayClient` and `ServiceFailover.ServiceGatewayClient` do they share an interface or smth ?

Comment: @Fabjan no. Only commonality is that they're the same thing but on different endpoints. So `OperationResponse` in the code is basically identical between the service and the failover but they're addressed differently as indicated

Comment: @HimBromBeere what kind of info would you need?

Comment: What do your `OperationResponse`-classes have in common? Can you extract a common interface for them?

Comment: If the two services don't share a common interface, you should *create* one by wrapping them both.  That way the basic functionality appears identical to calling code and the ways in which you leverage that common functionality it can be combined. Then you just pass in an interface pointer to the common function.

Comment: @HimBromBeere the `OperationResponse` classes are identical. Literally the only thing different between `Service.OperationResponse` and `ServiceFailover.OperationResponse` is the endpoint. The Failover service was designed as a backup in case the primary endpoint couldn't be reached for any particular reason.

Comment: Then you should extract a common base-class/-interface for both, so that you have only a single method (e.g. `ParseResponse`) accepting an instance of that class instead two methods

Comment: Could you write up an Answer to this effect? I don't actually have any idea where to begin :/

Answer (score 0):

Why can you not have just one response?

```
public class Response
{
}
public abstract class GetResponseBase
{
    public abstract Response GetResponse();
}
public class GetResponsePrimary : GetResponseBase
{
    public override Response GetResponse()
    {
        return new Response();
    }
}
public class GetResponseSecondary : GetResponseBase
{
    public override Response GetResponse()
    {
        return new Response();
    }
}
```